# Navigate through multiple divs using next and previous buttons

Tags: jquery

I already found a solution to this but i am new to JQuery.

How do you change it so that i can show three divs at a time and when the next or previous buttons are clicked it advances 1 instead of only showing one at a time.

Here is the JS Fiddle i was looking at:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/aVJBY/468/

and this is the JQuery:

```
   function updateItems(delta)
{
    var $items = $('#group').children();
    var $current = $items.filter('.current');
    $current = $current.length ? $current : $items.first();
    var index = $current.index() + delta;
    // Range check the new index
    index = (index < 0) ? 0 : ((index > $items.length) ? $items.length : index); 
    $current.removeClass('current');
$current = $items.eq(index).addClass('current');
// Hide/show the next/prev
$("#prev").toggle(!$current.is($items.first()));    
$("#next").toggle(!$current.is($items.last()));    
}
$("#next").click(function () {
updateItems(1);
});
$("#prev").click(function () {
updateItems(-1);
});
// Cause initial selection
updateItems(0);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it this way and it works great, but on the other hand I'm also sure there might be a way which is more optimized.

```
// give each div an id "#child1", "#child2", etc.
$("#group div").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr('id', "child" + (i + 1));
}); 

var First = 1;
var Second = 2;
var Third = 3;

$('#child'+First+', #child'+Second+', #child'+Third ).addClass('current');

// on next click, add +1 to First, Second and Third
$('#next').click(function(){
    if( !$('#child'+First).is(':last-child') ) {
        $("#group div").removeClass('current');
        First++;
        Second++;
        Third++;
        $('#child'+First+', #child'+Second+', #child'+Third ).addClass('current');
    }
});

$('#prev').click(function(){
    if( !$('#child'+Third).is(':first-child') ) {
        $("#group div").removeClass('current');
        First--;
        Second--;
        Third--;
        $('#child'+First+', #child'+Second+', #child'+Third ).addClass('current');
    }
});
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/551/

**edit:**
added `if(!$('#child'+First).is(':last-child'))` and
`if(!$('#child'+Third).is(':first-child'))` this way there's always at least the first or the last `div` visible

Comment: Where are the javascript dukes hiding? Sure there's a solution in less than 10 lines of code!

Comment: I edited the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aVJBY/552/
This way you always have at least the first or last div visible, they cannot all hide.

Answer (score 0):

you can give each div input id and using jquery buy clicking next you can get which input has active class and get it's id and then you can setfocuse the next on by adding +1 to the div name and -1 setfoces if you want to go back.

And remember to move the class name accordingly

You can use these jquery functions to do it

```
var active_div = $( .active );
$( P_active_div_id ).removeClass( "active" );
$( N_active_div_id ).addClass( "active" );
$( "#target" ).focus();
```

I hope that will help

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice)

```js
var group = $("#group")
, items = group.children().eq(0).addClass("current").addBack()
, buttons = $("#next, #prev")
, prev = buttons.filter("#prev").hide(0)
, next = buttons.filter("#next");

buttons.on("click", function (e) {
    var button = $(this)
    , idx = function (index) {
        return items.filter(".current").eq(index).index()
    }
    , _toggle = function (start, stop) {
        $(".current").hide(0, function () {
            $(this).removeClass("current");
            items.slice(start, stop)
            .addClass("current").show(0);
            prev.toggle(start > 0);
            next.toggle(stop < items.length)
        })
    };
    if (button.is(next) && idx(-1) + 4 <= items.length) {
        _toggle(idx(-1) + 1, idx(-1) + 4)
    } else if (button.is(prev) && idx(0) !== 0) {
        _toggle(idx(0) === 1 ? 0 : idx(0) - 3, idx(0))
    };
});
```

```css
#group div {
    display: none;
}
#group div.current {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#next, #prev {
    width: 100px;
    height 40px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
#next {
    float: right;
}
#prev {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="group">
    <div>one</div>
    <div>two</div>
    <div>three</div>
    <div>four</div>
    <div>five</div>
    <div>six</div>
    <div>seven</div>
    <div>eight</div>
    <div>nine</div>
    <div>ten</div>
</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
<div id="prev">prev</div>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q1quarfk/